# reverse the bevel

Tags: bevel

i'm new to blender and i have a stupid problem.. i made a "n" shape object and i want to use bevel on the end but when i try i get the opposite result [image: like this] or [image: this]
i want remove the edges ... if i select 1 edge and try to bevel and press <kbd>P</kbd> during the edit i get something near my objective... but only on 1 side ... i used bevel others time (not a lot) but is the first time i get a reverse bevel... (i tried to use <kbd>ctrl + n</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl + shift + n</kbd> too but without changes)

Comment: Have you tried to apply your transformation scale and rotation? In object mode, Press ctrl + A and select rotation and scale.

Comment: no, no idea what that command did .. but now it works :-) tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting profile to .5 after beveling as shown below:

[image: Bevel]

Hope that solves your problem!